# "NaCl plugin exited with status code 255" error on Chromebook SSH client?

Tags: ssh, debian, google-chrome-app, ssh-keys, google-chrome-os

When using SSH on my Chromebook using the Google Secure Shell app to connect to my Debian DigitalOcean droplet, the connection drops suddenly after around 2 minutes of use and I am receiving this error message:

```
NaCl plugin exited with status code 255.
(R)econnect, (C)hoose another connection, or E(x)it?
```

Any suggestions on what this is?
Many thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, on my Toshiba Chromebook ... :( ... the I found a possible solution with disabling a flag: enable-tcp-fast-open ... but it was already disabled, so the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just remove --no-proxy-host from config and it will work

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a NAT idle timeout in your home router.  Try adding `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes` to the "SSH Arguments" field of the connection dialog.

If it's not a NAT issue, then the second most likely option is that you've imported a config file (using Secure Shell's "Import..." link in the connection dialog) that specifies a `ServerAliveInterval`, which does not work properly in Secure Shell.

Comment: Adding TCPKeepAlive flag solved this issue for me, connecting from W10 via my home router. Thanks heaps!

Comment: This also may be happening to some people because SSH is being blocked by their network e.g. at certain office buildings or restaurants, etc. You can try using a VPN in those situations but VPNs might be blocked by firewalls, too.